# Vector tiles from SQLite database with Java

Tags: java, spatialite, vector-tiles, sqlite

Currently, I'm serving vector tiles exported from `QGIS` shapefile with `Export to PostgreSQL` function.

Is there any simple Java library that could be used to serve these vector tiles from SQLite database? I wanted basically to export shapefile from `QGIS` to `SQLite`/`SpatiaLite`, and then use those databases inside Java app that can expose HTTP endpoints for serving those data as vector tiles.

Answer (score 0):

If you export to a geopackage then GeoServer can server that as a vector tile set. Or you could write your own version using Geotools.

Comment: is geooackage also some file like sqlite database? I basically do not want to use adiitional server except embedded jetty inside my java app. could I ise geotools as java lib to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, but using an existing tool is much easier

Comment: yes, I'm trying to find existing java lib that I could just use (but without having to run it as a separate server).